# How to change side menu selection when top menuitem selected in openerp?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I am new to openerp. I need to change the left side menu action(i.e; If the Human Resources tab is selected it is automatically selected the Employees menuitem. In this case I need to change default menuitem i.e; Leave Requests to Approve) when Human Resources tab is selected. Please see the image.[image: side menu selection]

Please solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually loads the action that comes first. If you want 'Leave Request to Approve' to come first, then change the menu sequence to some thing less than the sequence of Employees.You can change it in `settings/technical/user interface/menu items`. For these menus, you should belong to the group `technical features`.Go to Settings/ Users/Users. Open the admin user record. Here you can see a tab called access rights.From here you can assign the group technical feature for the admin user

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am using openERP-7. I can't find this path in my opnerp-7. Where can I find the menu items ?.